# Is there to refer to a user without stating user.pk in a filter queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

For example, I want to get a list of `User`s. My current queryset looks like this

```
creator_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q(userprofile__place__managers=user) |
    Q(pk=user.pk)
)
```

I found out I could get the same result with `...managers=user.pk`

```
creator_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q(userprofile__place__managers=user.pk) |
    Q(pk=user.pk)
)
```

I used to write `...=user.pk` all the time until I realized I can simply drop the `pk` part. So in the second `Q()` clause, is it possible to remove the `pk` part as well? Thus I want to make it look like

```
creator_list = User.objects.filter(
    Q(userprofile__place__managers=user) |
    Q(something=user)
)
```

I understand that `pk` takes in the primary key, which is an integer, of the model, but why do I need to specify it when I already know that I want the filter through the `User` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. A field is required for field lookups, therefore the PK must be used since there is no way to refer specifically to the row indicated by a model.